# Azure not enable in Visual Studio SSIS Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I installed the Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services (SSIS). During the installation I got this message:

"64-bit SSIS is not found. This will only install 32-bit feature pack that can only be used with 32-bit SSIS (e.g in SSDT)"

When I run the visual studio, the Azure is disabled in the SSIS toolbox.

How can I fix this issue and make the Azure enable in the toolbox?

I have installed Visual Studio ver 16.6.5

I have installed SQL Server 2017 and 2019

My pc is 64-bit

Regards

Waleed

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running Visual Studio 2019 (16.6.5 as you say), you should check which version of the Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services you have installed.
The Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services version should match the targeted SQL Server version for your SSIS project (*Configuration Properties -> TargetServerVersion*).